# Stacked in Pagination in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, stacked

i'm new with CI and i tried a lot posibilities to make this run, but still it ain't working. Could you please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

So, Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('model_add','',TRUE);
}

public function _remap($a){
    if (isset($a) && !empty($a)):
        switch ($a) {
            case 'index':
                $this->index();
                break;

            default:
                $this->one_news($a);
                break;
        }
    endif;
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $home=$this->uri->segment(2);

    $limit=2;
    $offset=0;

    $query=$this->model_add->count_news($limit,$offset);

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/news/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tdt_news');
    $config['per_page'] = 2;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 2;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data = array('query' => $query,'page'=>$home);

    $data['news']           = $query;

    $this->load->view('main/header');
    $this->load->view('main/news', $data);
    $this->load->view('main/footer');
}
}
```

And the Model:

```
    function count_news()
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tdt_news` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $limit, $offset;");
    return $query->result();
}
```

I'll be very thankful for your help, thank you!

Comment: One mistake is there your count function is missing with parameters `function count_news()` should be  `function count_news($limit, $offset)`

Comment: you are renaming your model to empty string: `$this->load->model('model_add','',TRUE);` should be `$this->load->model('model_add');`

Comment: additionally, why are you using alternate syntax in your if statement but standard syntax in your switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a series of errors

- your count function in your model is missing parameters
- you should reformat the SQL string
- alternate and standard syntax in your view
- renamed model class to empty string

heres a fixed version,

**Controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_add');
    }

    public function _remap($a){
        if (isset($a) && !empty($a)) {
            switch ($a) {
                case 'index':
                $this->index();
                break;

                default:
                $this->one_news($a);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $home = $this->uri->segment(2);

        $limit = 2;
        $offset = 0;

        $query=$this->model_add->count_news($limit,$offset);

        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/news/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tdt_news');
        $config['per_page'] = 2;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data = array(  'query' => $query,
                        'page'=>$home,
                        'news' => $query);

        $this->load->view('main/header');
        $this->load->view('main/news', $data);
        $this->load->view('main/footer');
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
// with default parameters just in case
function count_news($limit = 50, $offset = 0)
{
    // and there is a nicer way to write your query
    // it works with multiple dbs thanks to active record
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $query = $this->db->get('tdt_news', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```